# Can I change my F-2 Visa to entrepreneur visa?

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa

My wife likes to go to US for her PhD degree. I have a programming company in our country that works around AI products. I want to know if we go to US, with F1 visa for her and F2 visa for me, can I participate in Science and Technology parks programs, get accepted my business plan/ideas and change my visa status to entrepreneur visa by creating a new programming/tech company in US?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "entrepreneur visa"?

Comment: @user102008: EB-1 or O-1 for example.

Comment: EB1 is an immigrant category, and includes EB1A for people of extraordinary ability, EB1B for outstanding professors, and EB1C for multinational managers. None of these are for entrepreneurs, unless you are also of extraordinary ability and are petitioning yourself. O1 is a nonimmigrant visa for people with extraordinary ability to work that requires a petition from the company that offers to employ you, and is not for entrepreneurs.

Comment: @user102008: What if I participate in incubators/accelerators programs and get accepted there and get funding, investment for my business idea to establish a new company in US?